# How to get all attributes and attributes data of a method using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

The end goal is to copy the attributes "as is" from a method to another method in a generated class.

```
public class MyOriginalClass
{
    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute2("value of attribute 2")]
    void MyMethod(){}
}

public class MyGeneratedClass
{
    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute2("value of attribute 2")]
    void MyGeneratedMethod(){}
}
```

I am able to list the attribute of the method using `MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes()` however, this does not give me the attributes arguments; which I need to generate the corresponding attribute on the generated class.

Note that I don't know the type of the attributes (can't cast the Attribute).

I am using CodeDom to generate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributesData() has the needed information:

```
// method is the MethodInfo reference
// member is CodeMemberMethod (CodeDom) used to generate the output method; 
foreach (CustomAttributeData attributeData in method.GetCustomAttributesData())
{
    var arguments = new List<CodeAttributeArgument>();
    foreach (var argument in attributeData.ConstructorArguments)
    {
        arguments.Add(new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodeSnippetExpression(argument.ToString())));
    }

    if (attributeData.NamedArguments != null)
        foreach (var argument in attributeData.NamedArguments)
        {
            arguments.Add(new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodeSnippetExpression(argument.ToString())));
        }

    member.CustomAttributes.Add(new CodeAttributeDeclaration(new CodeTypeReference(attributeData.AttributeType), arguments.ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: Can that code distinguish between the situations in my example above?

Comment: Yes, which is why there are two for loops, one for constructor arguments and one for named arguments. I tested it with both cases and got the annotations copied correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it would be possible to do this. GetCustomAttributes returns an array of objects, each of which is an instance of a custom attribute. There's no way to know which constructor was used to create that instance, so there's no way to know how to create the code for such a constructor (which is what the attribute syntax amounts to).

For instance, you might have:

```
[Attribute2("value of attribute 2")]
void MyMethod(){}
```

`Attribute2` may be defined as:

```
public class Attribute2 : Attribute {
    public Attribute2(string value) { }
    public Attribute2() {}
    public string Value{get;set;}
}
```

There's no way to know if it was generated by

```
[Attribute2("value of attribute 2")]
```

or by

```
[Attribute2(Value="value of attribute 2")]
```

Comment: Actually there is a way.. see my answer below.